# PowerBI Report Server IIS Reverse Proxy asks for credential but does not login

Tags: iis, reporting-services, powerbi, reverse-proxy, power-bi-report-server

I have a PowerBI Report Server installed in an IIS and works with all of these URLs:

```
localhost:8080/reports
HOSTNAME:8080/reports
10.1.10.10:8080/reports
```

And I am trying to do this with Reverse Proxy:

> localhost/OLAP --> localhost:8080/reports

I did what said in https://reda-bacha.medium.com/how-to-use-power-bi-report-server-with-a-reverse-proxy-3617827b008a, but when I reverse proxy this URL, it asks for credentials.

Then I enter the correct credentials but still no login and asks again.

I tested the reverse proxy with a wrong URL to get 404 error, which worked with no issue.

But the only issue is with this URL.

Am I missing something?

Windows Server 2022, IIS Version 10.0.20238.1.

Comment: Is this problem: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Power-BI-report-server-keeps-asking-for-credentials/m-p/2558456 similar to yours?

Comment: @TengFeiXie yes that was, and I did all it said and restarted PowerBI, but I'm still seeing credentials being asked.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem. You can use FRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr generate logs.